# function to increase splice index?

Tags: javascript, api

Is there a way that I could make a function that could increase the index of a variable i've created. for example I have let currentPage = mountId.slice(0, 1);    - but I want the page to go to let currentPage = mountId.slice(1, 2); when the next button is clicked

This is the code I have for my event listeners - for the left button (prev page) and right button (next page)

```
let index = 0;

const handleRightButtonClick = (e) => {
    index += 1;
    console.log(index);
};

const handleLeftButtonClick = (e) => {
    index -= 1;
    console.log(index);
};



rightButton.addEventListener('click', handleRightButtonClick); 

leftButton.addEventListener('click', handleLeftButtonClick);
```

the idea is I want to access the mount id which will be added onto a url to display results from fetch api call.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this can help you?
with just one function you can do what you are looking for.

```js
let index = 0;


// Funtion to add or reduce value of count
const count = (value)=> {
  index += value;
  console.log(index);
  return index;
}
```

```html
<!-- buttoms  -->
<button onclick="count(+1)">+</button>
<button onclick="count(-1)">-</button>
```